How to calculate sd of a log reduction
I have several log values, each value for a different day, all of them with a sd associated. I have to calculate a log reduction, which is basically the value of the first day minus the value of the last day.
How do i calculate the sd associated with the log reduction?
Thank you :)

Welcome to CV.  Could you clarify what you mean by "log" here? Would that be a logarithm or does it refer to some kind of data?  Regardless, it doesn't look like there's enough information to answer the question, because the SD of a difference (which is how you characterize a "log reduction") depends on whether the two values might be correlated and what their correlation coefficient is.  Perhaps you could describe your data with a little more detail?

Hi! Thank you. Basically, for each day of testing i have multiple values of CFU/g and then i calculated the logarithm of each value. Then, i calculated the mean of the logarithm results for each day and the standard deviation. Finally, i had to calculate the difference between the mean of the first day minus the mean of the last day. My question is about the standard deviation of these difference.

That helps; but the issue about correlation is a big one.  If these were CFU/g measurements for ongoing daily observations of the same things, they likely are strongly correlated; but if you used physically independent samples each day, then they likely are not correlated at all.  A good keyword to use in finding similar questions here is "repeated measurements."

Oh yes, they are of the same things, so they are correlated

Please add  new information as an edit to the post  and not only as comments. Comments on this site are often seen by very few, and can be deleted!
